# Is it possible to apply a filter on an items collection in the binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I understand how easy it is to apply a filter to something like a PagedCollectionView and then bind an ItemsSource to that.  Howerver in this case, I would like to bind a ComboBox to a StaticResource, but filter it based on a value in the ViewModel.  Is this sort of thing possible / practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible, yeah - but why use staticresource if you're doing MVVM? why is it not part of the ViewModel completely? if it's sorted by the VM, then it should also be hosted by the VM. otherwise it rather feels like you're crossing layer - boundries.